# How to access content from payload() received from Firestore with Arduino

Tags: json, object, arduino, esp32, arduino-c++

I'm using Arduino to read some data from Firestore, which is a database. I could successfully grab the data from the firestore using rest Api, and manage to get the Payload(), But I`m attempting to store some of these data into a boolean.
This is what I receive from the database:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "fields": {
    "nome_botao": {
      "stringValue": "botao1"
    },
    "nome": {
      "stringValue": "Quarto"
    },
    "icon": {
      "stringValue": "LightBulb"
    },
    "value": {
      "booleanValue": true
    }
  },
  "createTime": "2021-02-01T17:59:56.695439Z",
  "updateTime": "2021-02-01T18:13:49.703817Z"
}
```

I'm trying to store the booelanValue from my payload.
This is my code:

```
#if defined(ESP32)
#include <WiFi.h>
#elif defined(ESP8266)
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#endif
#include <Firebase_ESP_Client.h>

/* 1. Define the WiFi credentials */
#define WIFI_SSID "stuuf"
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "stuuf"

/* 2. Define the project ID */
#define FIREBASE_HOST "stuuf-stuuf-stuuf.firebaseio.com"
#define FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID "stuuf-stuuf-stuuf"
#define API_KEY "stuuf"

/* 3. Define the user Email and password that alreadey registerd or added in your project */
#define USER_EMAIL "stuuf"
#define USER_PASSWORD "stuuf"

bool currentState;

//Define Firebase Data object
FirebaseData fbdo;

FirebaseAuth auth;
FirebaseConfig config;

unsigned long dataMillis = 0;
int count = 0;

void setup()
{

    Serial.begin(115200);

    WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
    Serial.print("Connecting to Wi-Fi");
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
    {
        Serial.print(".");
        delay(300);
    }
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("Connected with IP: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    Serial.println();

    config.host = FIREBASE_HOST;
    config.api_key = API_KEY;

    /* Assign the user sign in credentials */
    auth.user.email = USER_EMAIL;
    auth.user.password = USER_PASSWORD;

    Firebase.begin(&config, &auth);
    Firebase.reconnectWiFi(true);

#if defined(ESP8266)
    //Set the size of WiFi rx/tx buffers in the case where we want to work with large data.
    fbdo.setBSSLBufferSize(1024, 1024);
#endif

    String content;

    FirebaseJson js;
}

void loop()
{

    if (millis() - dataMillis > 60000 || dataMillis == 0)
    {
        dataMillis = millis();

        String documentPath = "mypath";
        String mask = "";

        Serial.println("------------------------------------");
        Serial.println("Get a document...");

        if (Firebase.Firestore.getDocument(&fbdo, FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID, "", documentPath.c_str(), mask.c_str()))
        {
            Serial.println("PASSED");
            Serial.println("------------------------------------");
            Serial.println(fbdo.payload());
            Serial.println("------------------------------------");
            Serial.println();
        }
        else
        {
            Serial.println("FAILED");
            Serial.println("REASON: " + fbdo.errorReason());
            Serial.println("------------------------------------");
            Serial.println();
        }
    }
}
```

CurrentState is the bool value which will receive the "value" from the payload.

Answer (score 0):

Since the document you get from Firestore is JSON, you need a JSON parser to get your data out of it. For example: [ArduinoJson](https://arduinojson.org/)

Answer (score 0):

**You can check this out:**

```
// Create a FirebaseJson object and set content with received payload
FirebaseJson payload;
payload.setJsonData(fbdo.payload().c_str());

// Get the data from FirebaseJson object 
FirebaseJsonData jsonData;
payload.get(jsonData, "fields/pump/stringValue", true);
Serial.println(jsonData.stringValue);

if(jsonData.stringValue == "on"){
  digitalWrite(D1, HIGH);
}
```